# Reload page in Safari without resending form?

Tags: safari

Sometimes, I want to reload a page in Safari, but I submitted a form on the previous page. Is there any way, short of entering the URL bar (either with a mouse or with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and pressing <kbd>return</kbd>), to reload the page *without* resending the form?

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, no.  For simple HTML forms using Common Gateway Interface (CGI), the web page you see is the output of a process which uses the form data as an input.  Put another way, the server needs the form data to generate the page.  There a lot of ways to get around that using back-end databases, cookies, javascript, etc.  But generally speaking: no-form, no-result.

You mentioned clicking in the URL bar and pressing return, but if the form uses the GET method (form data in the URL itself), then clicking in the URL bar and pressing return does effectively resend it.  However, if the form uses the POST method (form data sent in the HTTP request body), then clicking the URL bar and pressing will not send the form data and so the page will not be regenerated.

Note that if you tell Safari to reload a form-result page, it will usually ask you to confirm that you really want to do that, then resend the form data.  The reason it asks is that there may well be some side-effect of the form (like charging your credit card) which you might not want to repeat.  That's poor CGI design, but it happens.

Comment: I knew most of that, but thank you for the detailed information! What I'm really looking for is a way to get Safari to do the same thing as resending the URL with a command-R.

Comment: What's wrong with command-R?  (I mean, there are a lot of things *wrong* with command-R, but what are you specifically trying to avoid?)

Comment: It warns me about resending the form. I then have two options: Resend (I don't want to resend it) and Cancel (I *do* want to reload it).

Comment: Those really are you're only two choices.  Without the form data, the server has no way of knowing what to send to you.

Comment: It does it when I resend the URL! That's all I want to do.

Comment: Some sites may cache the results and use a cookie to identify them, or use a combination of GET and POST so that some of the result data can be reproduced.  But in general, a POST form requires that the form be re-POSTed to generate the page again.  So even though clicking in the URL may work (or at least appear to to work) on some pages, it won't work on most and there is no standard shortcut to make Safari do that.